# How do I concatenate strings via command line arguments separated by a +?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, string-concatenation

What I want to do is write arguments in the command line separated by a + and concatenate the arguments into a single string
eg:

```
./concat Wow + this + is + cool
Wow this is cool
```

I looked up a question for this sort of topic before but that involved concatenating only the first character of each argument and not the entire arguments. And it didn't ignore the separator

This is what I have

```
void concat(char **argv, int argc, char *string)
{   
    size_t i = 0;

    for(int j=1; j<argc; j++)
    {
        string[i++] = *argv[j];
        if(j+1 != argc)
        {
            string[i++] = ',';
            string[i++] = ' ';
        }
    }
    string[i] = '\0';

}
```

And this is what I'm doing in main to call this function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int allnum=0;
    char string[1000];


    concat(argv, argc, string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Comment: Why you can't just print the alternate arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `strcpy` or `strcat` in `string.h` is more simple to concatenate string.

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char * s = malloc (2 * argc *sizeof (char));

    if (argc < 2)
        exit(-1);

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i += 2) {
        strcat(s, argv[i]);
        strcat(s, " ");
    }

    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```